# Accessing external Basler Camera in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, automation, basler

I am currently trying to access a Basler camera, that is connected to my computer via Ethernet, from Visual Studio. The camera is not displayed in the device manager, but I can ping it in the command prompt so I guess it is connected.
The general idea is to scan a surface and get a live picture.

This is the code snippet:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://172.20.1.40:80/?stream')
```

But as soon as I execute the program, I get the error that it is unable to open the camera.
If i do "cv2.VideoCapture(0) or (1), it also does not work.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Many thanks and regards

Comment: Depending on which camera USB 3.0 or 2.0?

Comment: It is connected only via ethernet

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you use an industrial series of Basler camera (ace / ace 2 etc.). These models are not IP cameras and do not produce RSTP stream. They rely on GigE Vision protocol.

In order to connect them to your python app:

1. download and install [pylon SDK](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/software/pylon/sdk/),
2. make sure that camera is running smoothly in Basler pylon Viewer
3. in your python project, install [pypylon](https://github.com/basler/pypylon),

```py
pip3 install pypylon
```

4. use [pypython/samples/opencv.py](https://github.com/basler/pypylon/blob/1c8636841df6eecb0592eb33d4caf1d6a6360268/samples/opencv.py#L2) as your starting sample project.

For full picture of your situation, please paste a model of camera.

Hope it helps.